# Dev cpp - Error while running: not a valid Win32 application

Tags: c++, gcc, dev-c++

I have recently started with `C++` and am using Dev cpp as my IDE. But whenever I compile and run the program for Dev cpp, the program compiles successfully but while running the `.exe` file I get the following error:

```
--------------------------------
Failed to execute "C:\Users\Karan Gandhi\Desktop\Untitled1.exe":
Error 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

> Please Note: I can successfully run the program from the terminal manually by just opening the file in the terminal: `"C:\Users\Karan Gandhi\Desktop\Untitled1.exe"`

Is there any way to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: how are you compiling it?

Comment: by the compile option in the ide

Comment: please provide all options/flags to provide a [mcve]

Comment: This was the command which I found:
`g++.exe "C:\Users\Karan Gandhi\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Karan Gandhi\Desktop\Untitled1.exe" -pg -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++" -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib" -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib" -static-libgcc -pg`

Comment: Since you're on Windows, I strongly recommend using [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/). Dev-C++ is an obsolete product; you will have a much easier time with Visual Studio.

Comment: Glad to help. I forgot to mention to look at the list of "Workloads" when you run the installer and turn on "Desktop development with C++" - I think it may not be selected by default. And you may want to turn off ".NET desktop development" if you're only using C++. After you install VS, there will be a "Visual Studio Installer" on your Start menu that you can use to add or remove workloads or individual components.